# python dictionary match key values in two dictionaries

Tags: python

In the below shown dictionaries i want to check whether the key in aa matches the key in bb and also the value corresponding to it matches in bb or not.Is there a better way to write this code

```
  aa = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
  bb = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

  for k in aa:
    if k in bb:
      if aa[k] == bb[k]:
         print "Key and value bot matches in aa and bb"
```

Comment: What is your desired result?  Do you want a single Boolean value indicating whether *all* keys in `aa` that also appear in `bb` have matching values?  Or one Boolean value per key?  Or some code that prints `"Key and value bot matches in aa and bb"` once for each matching key/value pair?

Comment: Hmm... Overlooking the issue with the way you iterate over `aa` (hint, that's the same as `aa.iterkeys()`), your basic approach is actually just fine.  What do you actually want to improve?

Comment: I somehow get the impression that everybody else seems to understand what Rajeev wants to do in the first place.  Yet the answers to completely different things…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use sets to find all equivalents:

```
for (key, value) in set(aa.items()) & set(bb.items()):
    print '%s: %s is present in both aa and bb' % (key, value)
```

The `&` operator here gives you the [intersection of both sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection); alternatively you could write:

```
set(aa.items()).intersection(set(bb.items()))
```

Note that this does create full copies of both dicts so if these are very large you this may not be the best approach.

A shortcut would be to only test the keys:

```
for key in set(aa) & set(bb):
    if aa[key] == bb[key]:
        print '%s: %s is present in both aa and bb' % (key, value)
```

Here you only copy the keys of each dict to reduce the memory footprint.

When using Python 2.7, the dict type includes [additional methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) to create the required sets directly:

```
for (key, value) in aa.viewitems() & bb.viewitems():
    print '%s: %s is present in both aa and bb' % (key, value)
```

These are technically [dictionary views](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) but for the purposes of this problem they act the same.

Comment: @Rajeev: No it is not! `&` is a logical operator, which on sets means `intersection of`. Updated the answer to include that info.

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND, not logical AND. But it doesn't really matter, because it's overloaded for sets.

Comment: The last code snippet (which looks very similar to the one in my answer) only works in Python 2.7, not in "2.7 or up".

Comment: Well, there may some day be a Python 2.8 (although I doubt it). Removed the 'or up' for now.

Comment: Oh, the joys of Python humor, we have much to be thankful for. :-D

Answer (score 7):

This can be written as one-liner with `all`:

```
all(bb[k] == v for k, v in aa.iteritems() if k in bb)
```

It's also more declarative approach, which might convey the intent better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over all matching key/value pairs, you can use

```
for key, value in aa.viewitems() & bb.viewitems():
    ...
```

(Python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
bb = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

[k for k,v in aa.items() if k in bb]

['a', 'b']
```

Python 3

Comment: This answer does not check for values being equal as well. It needs to be something like this instead: `[k for k,v in aa.items() if k in bb and bb[k] == v]`