# compare two dictionary and display the image based on the key in python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, dictionary

How can i compare two dictionary and based on the matching keys I have to display the images. I mean if the key matched with the first dictionary and its in the second too, then i have to take the image based on the key. I have given a try, and the code is:

```
for key in res_lst_srt:
   if key in resizedlist:
       b,g,r = cv2.split(images[i])
       img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
       plt.subplot(2,3,i+1),plt.imshow(img)
       plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

I have taken the query image seperately, and i have got the distance between the query image,and all the database image. Distance have key and value, database image have key and value. I want to retrieve the image which matches the best with minimum distance based on key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your description I take that you have a set of images and each has a set of keys associated. You probably have a query which is a set of keys as well and the task to select those images which match the query best according to some metric. Please confirm, correct and deliver details about the task (data structures, metric).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not properly into the dict concept, you should study it a little bit to understand how it works with simple elements (number, strings) and only when you got it try with the heavy datas as opencv images.

Try this piece of code:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'e':1, 'd':2, 'c':4}

print dict1
print dict2

# note that this code is not optimized!!
# there are plenty of ways you can do better
# but prob. is the easiest way == better way to understand it
for k1 in dict1.keys():
    for k2 in dict2.keys():
        if k1==k2:
            print 'keys matches'
            mergedvalues = dict1[k1] + dict2[k2]
            print 'merged value is:', merged values
```

for better ways to compare two dicts going deep in python way of handling dict and other data structures (as list, set, etc) and operations on that, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832373/python-dictionary-match-key-values-in-two-dictionaries) is nice. but I think you should understand how dict works before.