# Python3: Comparing a specific pair of keys and values between two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

**EDIT: In case it helps with context, I am actually trying to generalize this to work in for and while loops, where I would want something like this to work**

```
if dictA[certainkey:'certainvalue'] == dictB[certainkey:'certainvalue']:
    return True
```

**Original Question:**
Is there a way to compare identical keys in two dictionaries in Python3 to see if they have the same values?

For example, let's say

```
dictA = {1:'Y', 2:'E', 3:'E'}
dictB = {1:'Y', 2:'A', 3:'W'}
```

I want the program to return me a True value if a certain set of key-value pairs in dictA matches the same set of key-value pairs in dictB. In this case, key 1 is paired to value 'Y' in both dictA and dictB. I didn't know if there were good ways to do this, so I naturally tried

```
print(dictA[1:'Y'] == dictB[1:'Y'])
```

hoping to get a True printed to me. Since it didn't work (and I don't know enough about dictionaries yet), I was wondering if there were alternative ways of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge the dicts on equal (key, value) pairs and then run subsequent checks against the merged dict.

```
>>> dictA = {1:'Y', 2:'E', 3:'E'}
>>> dictB = {1:'Y', 2:'A', 3:'W'}
>>> 
>>> merged = dict(dictA.items() & dictB.items())
>>> merged
{1: 'Y'}
>>> 
>>> 1 in merged
True
>>> 3 in merged
False
```

Creating `merged` is painless because the return values of `dict.keys`, `dict.values` and `dict.items` support the `set` interface with regards to operations such as union, intersection, etc.

Caveat: requires hashable values in your dicts. If you have unhashable values, create `merged` via

```
>>> b_items = dictB.items()
>>> merged = dict(pair for pair in dictA.items() if pair in b_items)
```

Comment: I edited my question a bit to reflect the fact that I'm actually trying to generalize this to work in for loops, so I want to check if a certain key:value pair matches the same key:value pair in another dictionary.

Comment: @Ferreroire `for ...: if key in merged: <do something>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to implement a beautiful solution with the merged approach. Marking this question as answered with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First get the matching keys between the dictionaries, then use a dictionary comprehension to compare each of these matching keys.

```
matching_keys = dictA.keys() & dictB.keys()

>>> {k: dictA[k] == dictB[k] for k in matching_keys}
{1: True, 2: False, 3: False}
```

To just get the keys where the values match, use a list comprehension:

```
keys_with_matching_values = [k for k in matching_keys if dictA[k] == dictB[k]]
# Or: [k for k in dictA if k in dictA and dictA[k] == dictB[k]]

>>> keys_with_matching_values
[1]
```

Note that both methods are memory efficient, as one does not needlessly store the matching values in the dictionaries.

Comment: I was going to come up with my own answer using a `for` loop, but @Alexander has the answer you really want.

Comment: @OP, consider this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832373/python-dictionary-match-key-values-in-two-dictionaries

Comment: You opened eyes for me! The `&` operator will make my code much easier to read! I usually used intersection, but this is much easier to understand and maintain!

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in dictA
    i = 0
    if key in dictA:
        word = dictA[0][i]
        if dictA[0][i] == dictB[0][0]:
            print(word + 'matches dict 0')
        if dictA[0][i] == dictB[0][1]:
            print(word + 'matches dict 1')
        if dictA[0][i] == dictB[0][2]:
            print(word + 'matches dict 2')
            i += 1
```

I wrote this really quick on the shuttle from work, its sloppy and I could make a loop for dictB. But this should work for automating the process of finding the word. (But may not work, because I wrote it quick)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do what you mentioned in a list comprehension

```
print([True if dicta[k] == dictb[k] else False for k in dicta])
# [True, False, False]
```

Expanded

```
for k in dicta:
    if dicta[k] == dictb[k]:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

Comment: In case of keys not present in both dicts, you'd have to catch the `KeyError` (or hash again by performing an `in` check).

Comment: @timgeb yep that crossed my mind, but for this specific case not needed, if Op found this useful and that was a additional factor I would add in, but don't want to over complicate if not neccessary